# How to check if first children params in a url without throwing null error in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to use the same component (`SigninFormComponent`) for different children (`confirm` in the code below) what I am facing here is that as long the child route is active the code works fine, once I switch back to the parent route I receive this error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of null

the error is obvious but how can I check without throwing an error?

My routes config,

```
......
 { path: 'web', component: WebsiteHomeComponent, children: [
        { path: 'welcome', component: WebsiteWelcomeComponent },
        { path: 'signin', component: SigninFormComponent, children: [
            {path: ':confirm', component: SigninFormComponent}
        ] }, .....
```

I am trying to check in this way,

```
  ngOnInit() {
   if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.params['confirm']) {
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
      (param: Params) => {
        this.confirmUserId = param['userId'];
        this.confirmUserIdCode = param['code'];
        this.ConfirmEmailAddress();
      });
   }
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      'uniqueId': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      'password': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'rememberMe': new FormControl(false)
    });
  }
```

for now I solved it just by searching the url for matching string,

```
if (routeUrl.indexOf('confirm') > -1) {
      ......
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild && this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.params['confirm']) {
```

this way `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.params['confirm']` is only checked when `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild` is truthy (`null` is falsey)